# Import Vulcan software files into QGIS

Tags: qgis, import

I have a file with the extension .00t that represents the route of a vehicle, I would like to import it into QGIS to edit it as a shapefile.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I have to use GlobalMapper v24 to do this. https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/knowledgebase/global-mapper-24/Formats/Vulcan3D_Triangulation.htm then export to shapefile.